# How to add logging in step function configuration for EMR serverless Job

Tags: logging, pyspark, amazon-emr, aws-step-functions, emr-serverless

I am executing pyspark script on EMR serverless and i am using AWS step function for creating EMR application and submitting job in it. I want to know how to add logging option in AWS step function configuration while creating EMR application or submitting job in it so that i can see log files from spark job run in cloudwatch or in s3.
this is my current block from StartJobRun state from AWS step function configuration.

"EMR Serverless StartJobRun": {
"Type": "Task",
"Resource": "arn:aws:states:::emr-serverless:startJobRun",
"Parameters": {
"ApplicationId.$": "$.ApplicationId",
"ExecutionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam:/demo-emrserverless-iam-role",
"JobDriver": {
"SparkSubmit": {
"EntryPoint": "s3://demo/test.py",
"EntryPointArguments.$":[],
"SparkSubmitParameters": "--conf
}
},

i tried to add "JobConfiguration" but it is  not accepting JobConfiguration